# Porque não consigo usar Listener do OnbackPressed dentro de fragment

Tags: android

Tenho um navigation drawer que abre varios fragments, quero que ao clicar e voltar, verificar a visibilidade de um layout e fazer algo com isso, e vez de fechar o app, porem não consigo fazer override no backpressed dentro do fragment, tentei fazer um listener com a view, mas não funcionou.

```
    package doupenglish.com.br.doup.Fragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import doupenglish.com.br.doup.MainActivity;
import doupenglish.com.br.doup.R;
import mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton;


public class PreparacaoFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ConstraintLayout layoutunit,layoutdia;
    private FancyButton btnunit1,btnunit2,btndia1;

    public PreparacaoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preparacao, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        layoutunit = view.findViewById(R.id.layoutunit);
        layoutdia = view.findViewById(R.id.layoutdia);
        btnunit1 = view.findViewById(R.id.btnunit1);
        btnunit1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btndia1 = view.findViewById(R.id.btndia1);
        btndia1.setOnClickListener(this);

        view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int keycode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                    if(layoutunit.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                        layoutunit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        layoutdia.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.btnunit1:
                layoutunit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutdia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case R.id.btnunit2:

                break;
            case R.id.btndia1:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Layout Exercicios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu pode criar um listener para isso, algo que vai levar um bom punhado de código, ou pode utilizar o `onDetach` no seu `Fragment` para fazer isso.

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    SEU CÓDIGO AQUI
}
```

Acredito que isso vá resolver seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um listener implementa-lo em todos os fragments e no OnBackPressed da sua Activity notificar os listeners.

Espero ter ajudado!